# How to compile a normal .h-.c object build and get the same level of optimization as with a static "unity" build, in gcc?

Tags: c

I have been told that ["unity builds"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_build) have a greater chance to inline everything if you make all the functions static, and thus make the binary more optimized and faster.

Personally I don't like them because the classic way is much more intuitive and modular, and you don't have to keep track of headers between branching .c files and main.c, and you don't have to have a master declaration header (basically emulating the normal way).

I don't care about compilation time, but I do care about efficiency of the program. So in my mind, the question is why wouldn't a compiler be able to do all these optimizations regardless of objects and whatnot, even if it had to compile twice or several times?

So how do I do that?

Comment: Look into "whole program optimization" / "link time optimization"

Comment: This seems like premature optimization to me. Build good, maintainable code that works. *Then* consider things like optimizations, but only if there are explicit requirements about it, and the program doesn't perform according to those requirements. If you need to optimize, then take a compiler-optimized build to measure, benchmark and profile. Find the top *three* bottlenecks, and optimize those. If the new build doesn't match the requirements, find the top *two*. And the top *one*.

Comment: Also, hand-optimizing code tend to make it harder to read, understand and maintain. So write plenty of documentation and comments about what the code is doing, what algorithms it's using, what optimizations were made, and *why* the optimization was needed.

Comment: "Does the project have a master header including every header in the project?" is pretty much a standard thing to check on the "was this project badly designed" list.

Comment: I take it that you're only interested in optimizing for speed and not size? If you're target is an embedded platform with limited resources then inlining code may not be the way to go.